# Looking for a place to buy bitcoin with a credit card

Tags: buy-bitcoins, trade, bitcoin-credit-card

I'm trying to find a fast, reliable and secure place/service I can buy Bitcoins using a credit/debit card.

I googled and saw a few websites but most are a little sketchy and the rest don't seem to accept cards anymore.

Any suggestions?

Comment: We would need to know what country you are in to be able to suggest an appropriate place.

Comment: I'm currently in Brazil but i have international credit/debit cards.

Comment: To understand why people are reluctant to accept cards when selling bitcoin, see http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3952/why-is-bitcoin-so-susceptible-to-credit-card-fraud?rq=1

Comment: Thanks that was really helpful. It makes a lot of sense... even though i would still prefer to buy with a prepaid credit card... that way i dont have to use my bank info etc online.

Answer (score 1):

you can try [Cubits](https://cubits.com), they are Bitcoin payment processor based in UK and Germany.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried few places and by far http://247exchange.com is the best - their fees are reasonable, the process is quite simple and although I had to verify myself it was quite fast and easy

Answer (score 0):

Try [CoinCorner](https://www.coincorner.com) - all major credit cards and debit cards accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I love using https://localbitcoins.com/, a buyers and sellers marketplace. The range of payment types you can use are amazing. (I.e.: cash, PayPal, direct deposit, credit card, etc)

Answer (score -2):

Circle.com Is a great place to buy bitcoin via credit card